# How to redact query string parameter from fastify pino logs

Tags: node.js, fastify, pinojs

I'm using Fastify and would like to redact querystring parameters in the logged request, eg:

`"url": "/auth?token=XXXXXXX"`

I've looked through the pino documentation on [redaction](https://github.com/pinojs/pino/blob/master/docs/api.md#redact-array--object), and can't find how to replace just part of the `url` value and not the whole thing.

How can I redact just part of the URL? Is it possible to specify a regex somewhere?

Comment: Could you consider logging the base URL and the query parameters separately?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon, yes, it's an option. how to do this?